# Are toad's spots red or white?

Tags: super-mario-bros

I am a bit confused by the color of Toad's hat.

I remember it being red with white spots but it seems like all the new Nintendo games have Toad have Toad having red spots.

Comment: What are "all the new games"? And why don't you compare the games you're referring to by searching for footage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Toad has always had a white hat with red spots in the games, and this is his canonical look.

[image]

However, adaptations have occasionally shown Toad with a red hat and white spots (which may be the source of your confusion), such as the TV show:

[image]

and the Nintendo Power Comics:

[image]

[Source](https://www.mariowiki.com/Toad)